# JQuery to vanilla JavaScript translation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in jQuery:

```
    $('body').on('click', '#gtco-offcanvas ul a:not([class="external"]), .main-nav a:not([class="external"])', function (event) {

        var section = $(this).data('nav-section');

        if ($('[data-section="' + section + '"]').length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('[data-section="' + section + '"]').offset().top - 55
            }, 500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        }
```

and I need to rewrite it in pure vanilla JS. I have tried to do this, but I just got a lot of errors and don't know how to correct them...

This is my version of the code:

```
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.closest('body #gtco-offcanvas ul a:not([class="external"]), .main-nav a:not([class="external"])')) {

            var section = document.querySelector('data').dataset('nav-section');

            if (document.querySelectorAll('[data-section="' + section + '"]').length) {
                document.querySelectorAll('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: document.querySelectorAll('[data-section="' + section + '"]').offset().top - 55
                }, 500, 'easeInOutExpo');
            }
        };
```

And the output is:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null`

If I try to let this line in jQuery to test that the rest part of the code is working, I get no errors, but it doesn't do anything also...

Comment: does `document.querySelector('data')` return anything? I would guess that it is `null`.

Comment: you are searching for a new element with `document.querySelector('data')` and not referencing the element clicked like on jQuery with `$(this)`

Comment: @callback yes, it's null...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your html element has the data attribute `data-nav-section=""` what you are looking for would be:

```
var section = e.target.dataset.navSection;
```

`e.target` would be the equivilant of `$(this)` and [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) is not a function but a property having to use a camelcase naming convention when using dashes in the attribute name

Comment: Thanks, you are right, now it returns something :) But I have a new error: `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).offset is not a function`...

Comment: `.offset()` is a jQuery function, [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) would be the property, so `.offsetTop` instead of `.offset().top`

Comment: Additionally to that you might need to revise your [`animate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) as this is somehting different on vanilla js as well

Comment: @user3063909 Please check relevant docs first: `querySelectorAll()` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), and unlike in jQuery, you cannot directly call element methods on that.

Comment: Thanks! Any link where I can find an example of how can I rewrite the animate function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) method without the `closest` to test if the receiving element is the one delegated:

```
if (e.target.matches('#gtco-offcanvas ul a:not([class="external"]), .main-nav a:not([class="external"])')) {    
    var section = e.target.dataset['navSection'];
    // ...
}
```